# background image same as html: why?

Tags: css

I have been attempting to dissect some of the css on the behance.net site. I've looked through it in the chrome inspector pretty thoroughly, but some things I just don't understand.

On the top navigation bar, there is text that says "Discover", "Galleries", "Jobs" and it is written within div `class="nav-text"` But also it has the class `nav-sprite` which includes the background image

```
nav-sprite {
background: url("http://assets.behance.net/img/sprites/nav.png?cb=1056284268") no-repeat;
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

The background url here leads to a png that has the same text as is written in html, but in one large image. Here it is on a black background. First of all, it's incredibly low resolution; Secondly, why is it even there if those same things are written in the html anyway?
[image: screenshot of background url image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the image instead of text most likely because of the font.  text-indent: -9999px sets the text off the page and there is also CSS like on the nav-sprite:

```
background-position: -300px 0;
height: 14px;
width: 75px;
```

These set the portion of the image to show.

The reason people put the text is for search engine purposes and if css is turned off.

Comment: thanks! I didn't notice that it wasn't the html i was seeing, but rather the image. makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 1):

It's given to render with a custom font properly, since IE6 is still in use and doesn't (properly) support custom fonts.

To answer the question properly though, the idea is that the HTML layout should still make semantic sense without any of the styles, both for accessibility and fallback purposes. This ensures that, and replaces the items in the menu with richer elements if there is full support.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML text is there only for the search engine robots or text-based browsers, akin to Lynx (or those without the CSS support). You will not see it due to `text-indent: -9999px;` in the style declaration you quoted. Instead, you will see a sprite from the `background-image`, specified by a class for the particular nav item. E.g.,

```
.nav-sprite-jobs {
    background-position: -269px 0;
    height: 11px;
    width: 30px;
}
```